# generating table with text box

Tags: javascript, html

I've a bit of experience coding in php but am fairly new to js. What I'm trying to do in js is create a simple order form, each line is to have a text box indicating the quantity to be ordered, product name and product price, with the latter to be populated from product array prod. My fairly rudimentary first attempt appears below, which needless to say doesn't work.

```
<body onload="populate()">
<table id="demo">
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>

<script>
function populate(){
var prod; //array of objects with name and price attributes
var table = document.getElementById("theTable");

for (var i=0; i<prod.length; i++)
    {

    var newTr = table.insertRow(-1);
    var numOrdered=document.createElement('input');
    numOrdered.type='text';
    numOrdered.id= "product "+i; //assigning id of "product i" to each product i
    newTr.insertCell(0).appendChild(num);
    newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(prod["name"]));
    newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(prod["price"]));
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the snippet at the bottom.

what's changed is:

in this line you targeted the wrong id, should have been 'demo'

```
var table = document.getElementById("theTable");
```

you also needed to reference the correct value in your array inside the loop:

```
document.createTextNode(prod["name"]);
```

to:

```
document.createTextNode(prod[i]["name"]);
```

and lastly this line:

```
newTr.insertCell(0).appendChild(num);
```

to:

```
newTr.insertCell(0).appendChild(numOrdered);
```

hope this helps.

```js
function populate() {
    var prod = [{
        name: 'box',
        price: 20
    }, {
        name: 'plane',
        price: 40
    }]; //array of objects with name and price attributes
    var table = document.getElementById("theTable");

    for (var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {

        var newTr = table.insertRow(-1);
        var numOrdered = document.createElement('input');
        numOrdered.type = 'text';
        numOrdered.id = "product " + i; //assigning id of "product i" to each product i
        newTr.insertCell(0).appendChild(numOrdered);
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(prod[i]["name"]));
        newTr.insertCell(-1).appendChild(document.createTextNode(prod[i]["price"]));
    }
}

populate();
```

```html
<table id="theTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can say that you change this line too : newTr.insertCell(0).appendChild(num);

Comment: Thanks, I got sloppy there after countless edits/iterations. I hadn't realized how close I was to getting it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

I am using jQuery, to create, append and iterating the array(each Loop).It is a better and effective way. Please use jQuery for DOM manipulation.

HTML:

```
<table id="demo">
<thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

CSS:

```
table,td{display:block}
th{width:100px}
td{margin:10px}
```

JS:

var prod=[{product:'samsung',price:100},{product:'apple',price:200},{product:'micromax',price:300}];

```
(function($){
$.each(prod,function(index,value){
$('#demo th:eq(0)').append("<td><input type='text'></td>");
$('#demo th:eq(1)').append("<td>"+value.product.toUpperCase()+"</td>");
$('#demo th:eq(2)').append("<td>"+value.price+"</td>")
});
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the JSFiddle Link:

https://jsfiddle.net/Dee0565/8vww1pwf/